# next/previous stays within specific taxonomy term when in single post

Tags: customization, custom-taxonomy, archives

I have created several taxonomies for my photoblog. When you click on a camera model (for example), you get to the archive page for that taxonomy term. It displays all the photos taken with that camera model (i.e., tagged with that specific term). I'm using the default view of the archive, so right now I don't have any custom archive/taxonomy files set up. So far so good. but if you click on a post from the archives page, it take you from mysite.com/camera-model/d70s (the archive page with the list of posts) to mysite.com/name-of-post.

How do I get it so that when you click on that post, you get mysite/camera-model/d70s/name-of-post? And then the next question is how do I get the next/previous links ot only scroll through the posts with (in this example) D70s tagged?

If this is possible, is it also possible to make it work across all terms or would I need specific coding for each term?

Thanks.